# ModX Evo: Search resources and TV's - display results with ditto

Tags: search, filter, content-management-system, modx, modx-evolution

Using ditto I have created a product catalogue. I now wish to add search and filtering options. Would anyone know the best way to do this? I cannot seem to find a good plugin.

I am running ModX Evolution 1.0.6

Comment: AjaxSearch is a great plugin that has all the options you are requesting.

Comment: @OptimusCrime Yes I tried that but couldnt figure out how use Ditto with it to display my custom template chunks. Did I miss something?

Comment: @MeldingDog : Ah, I overlooked that part. Btw, in yuor snippet (if it's inside modx) it would be quicker to use `$modx->runSnippet` rather than echoing the snippet-call in templatemode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and made my own if anyone's interested:

**Updated with full code**

Please feel free to ask me to clarify anything or add changes or improvments.

Note there is one problem that I must fix - that you cannot combine the TV's serach terms to make a very definitive search. I will still work on this

```
//TV FILTERS
$sql = 'SELECT DISTINCT `contentid` FROM `modx_site_tmplvar_contentvalues`';
$where = array();
//ADD THE VARIABLES YOU WANT TO SEARCH TV's WITH BELOW
if ($searchlocation !== 'Any') $where[] = '`value` LIKE "%'.$searchlocation.'%"';
if ($searchmake !== 'Any')  $where[] = '`value` LIKE "%'.$searchmake.'%"';
if ($searchtype !== 'Any') $where[] = '`value` LIKE "%'.$searchtype.'%"';
if (count($where) > 0) {
  $sql .= ' WHERE '.implode(' OR ', $where);
} else {
  // OPTIONAL
  // Error out; must specify at least one!
}

$tvqresult = mysql_query($sql);
$num_rowstvq = mysql_num_rows($tvqresult);
while ($rowtvq = mysql_fetch_array($tvqresult)) {
$contid =  $rowtvq['contentid'];

//MAIN QUERY RETRIEVES RESOURCE - TEMPLATE LIMITS SEARCH TO PARTICULAR TYPE THAT WILL BE USED IN DITTO
$mainsql = 'SELECT * FROM `modx_site_content` WHERE `id` = ' . $rowtvq['contentid'] . '  AND `template` = 12';

$resultmain = mysql_query($mainsql);
$num_rowsmain = mysql_num_rows($resultmain);
if (!$resultmain) {
continue;
}
elseif ($num_rowsmain == 0){
echo "Sorry - nothing matches your search";
}

else {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultmain )) {
  echo "[[Ditto? &parents=`134` &documents=" . $row['id'] . " &tpl=`usedtempchunk`]]";
}//END MAIN LOOP

}//END MAIN ELSE

}//END TV WHILE LOOP
?>
```